# Redis - server displaying nothing after long inactivity

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using Redis Store with node js on Ubuntu server.

After long inactivity with the nodejs and Redis, when I try to access node application Redis server returns empty data. It returns the data only after I restart Redis server.

I've also checked redis.conf, It has timeout disabled.

timeout 0

Comment: Don't you use expire to manage a time-to-live property? What is your maxmemory setting? Can you connect and have visibility on your data with redis-cli before restarting it? Can you run an info command?

Comment: I'm able to see all the keys from redis-cli. Here is the output of info command. [link](http://pastebin.com/DgbDt5zA)

Comment: It seems you have just posted the content of info after Redis restart. What is interesting would be to run it once the node.js app does not see anymore the keys.